# JQuery $.post() submitting multiple forms instead of just one

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a page with several forms on one page.  I have a button (outside all forms) that I want to submit only ONE form, but all form data is getting submitted from all forms.

```
$("#indiv_save").click( function() {
    alert($("#indiv_form").serialize());  // Shows only correct form
    $.post("/admin/update", $("#indiv_form").serialize(), function(data) {
        notify(data); // quick and easy feedback
    });
});
```

The alert() call shows exactly what I want to submit, but then Firebug shows fields being submitted from all forms after the .post(), even though the serialize() function is identical.

All forms have different names and element ids.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have only one `#indiv_form`, right?

Comment: What does you HTML look like?

Comment: Yes, there is only one #indiv_form.  (And to reply to another answer, the forms are of course accompanied by their own `<form>` tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making an ajax POST and returning. Depending on your button, it's going to attempt to submit the page's forms. What you need to do is prevent the default action:

```
 $('#indiv_save').click(function(e)
 {
      e.preventDefault();
      // Your Code Here
 });
```

Comment: I seem to have had multiple problems, and this was definitely one of them, because the buttons were not outside ALL forms as I had intended.

Answer (score 1):

The default action for your button is probably "submit the form", and you are not preventing it.

Return false from your click function should do it.

Answer (score 0):

The forms can't be inside a single all encompassing `<form>` tag, they have to be separated out in individual `<form>`'s instead.